# Grafana Singlestat: select with timerange

Tags: grafana

I am trying to use the `SingleStat` Plugin of Grafana to add an online/offline indicator to one of my dashboards.

So what I have so far is this with an influxdb datasource:
[image]

What I am missing is the option to define a timerange for this query. Lets say I want the count() of the last 30min. If the count is 0 I know that the server is offline. If the count is > 0 he is online. (For example my server adds a new entry every 20min. So if I don´t have an entry in the last 30min I know he must be offline)

So is it possible to get define a query with a timerange? When yes how ?

**UPDATE**
This is what I have so far now. But I get an error now which says *a.form is undefined*. Alos if I have a entry in the last 35min it doesnst switch to online.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singlestat panel uses, by default, the timerange of the dashboard it is placed on. 
For your case, make use of the 'override relative time' on the Time range tab and set it to "30m".
When using the count as you described, turn coloring on and set the threshold to 1. This will change the coloring when no entry is present (count is 0) in the last 30 minutes.

Comment: Looking at the error that's now visible in the question, I suggest you go back to the metrics tab and verify your query is correct. Verify the hostname etc.

Comment: thank you solved it. The problem was that i wrote min instead of m